# How to get ids of the form fields that have been removed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form where you can dynamically add and remove fields (this is done using javascript). The user can create a sale and add products to the sale, save the info and edit it afterwards if they want to. Each product has several fields like id (hidden), name, discount, ... and in the form you can add and remove products. Because the fields can be dynamically added and removed I have encountered a problem where if the user is editing the form and removes existing products, how can I get the ids of the products that have been removed in order to delete them from the database. How can I post this info with the rest of the form? What would be the best way to do it?

Btw, I am using PHP, HTML and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

With dynamic stuff like that I generally use JSON.

Build a json object in javascript with any content they've added, removed, changed, etc and send that instead of all the hidden inputs.

Even better would be to capture the action the user is performing and send that via ajax as it happens instead of in bulk.  Then you won't have to maintain state in the browser on what has changed in the form.  If a user deletes an item, you make an ajax call out saying they're deleting that item id.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of "it depends," but I can give you one example.

Let us say that you have a row of fields that looks like this:

```
<input name="part-number1" id="part-number1">
<input name="qty1" id="name="qty1">
<button id="delete-button1">Remove this item</button>
```

You could, if you wished, parse the ID of the button and try to extract out the row number. That, however, is difficult and error prone. There is a simpler way:

Remove this item

Then, in your Javascript, you can simply do something like this to attach an event listener:

```
// Note the use of event delegation here so we can add and remove rows without
// breaking the listener
$(window).on("button", "[data-row-idx]", function() {
  var id = $(this).getAttribute("data-row-idx");
  // Now you can use the 'id' to remove the elements from the screen
  // Or make an Ajax call.
});
```

to round things out, you can create that button and set the attribute with:

```
var $button = $("<button />").setAttribute("data-row-idx", 10);
```

And append that to your document as needed.

Answer (score 0):

How the user is removing the product? By clicking probably a `button` or an `icon`.

If so it should be easy.

The `code` listening to the `click` event and applying the `style` `display:none` or removing the `node`; `parentNode.removeChild(node)` can easily get the corresponding details, most likely from `data-attributes` associated with the `node`, to be removed.

In other words this is kind of `two way data binding`. Best approach would be to consider the interface as an `JavaScript object` and have `1-1` mapping. When ever the object gets modified update the interface and vice verse.